# How do I use this jQuery-plugin/ What am I doing wrong when setting up my jQuery-plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to understand how to use jQuery plugins, and in this case, [THIS](http://formstone.it/components/wallpaper/) plugin. If someone can help me explain what I'm doing wrong that would be awesome :)

So, this is what I've done. I've created my basic setup with index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="bower_components/Wallpaper/jquery.fs.wallpaper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/Wallpaper/jquery.fs.wallpaper.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>



<!-- Add your site or application content here -->  

<script>
    $("#element").wallpaper({
        source: "bekkevika3.jpg"
    });
</script>

<div id="element">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The links all load except for style.css as I haven't created it yet.

However, nothing happens. My div doesn't get my chosen image applied to it, what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

Here's a [screenshot](http://oi60.tinypic.com/yz71w.jpg) of what my printed html looks like. I find it very weird that it knows the size of the image, yet there's no actual image..

Comment: Don't know how the plugin works exactly, but I assume it sets the background image of the `div` to the given source. However, your `div` is empty, thus has a height of 0px. So I am guessing the image loads fine, it's just that you can't see it. Give the `div` a height > 0, or add some text.

Comment: put your `script` and especially the `link` tag inside your `head` tag and call first the css and then the javascript.... or the `script` tag to the bottom

Comment: Giving a height does not make any difference, neither does putting the tags inside the head.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referesh the page in browser with Developer Tools (Firebug) opened and check if you have some errors...

Are you sure you use correct path?:

```
source: "bekkevika3.jpg"
```

The other reason may be you apply plugin on element that currently not exists. In this case you should use:

```
$(function(){
     //put here your code. It will be executed only after whole elemtnes on page will be loaded
});
```

EDIT:

```
<style>
    #element { padding-top: 50%; }
</style>
```

Comment: I have one error as previously stated which is the missing style.css file that I've left out. I've tried placing the image in a regular <img> tag and it displays the image fine, so the path is correct :)

Comment: Put them there, but currently makes no difference :(

Comment: @michaelw90, try to add style that I added in answer.

Comment: Wrapping the script in the DOM ready handler worked like a charm, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#element").wallpaper({
            source: "bekkevika3.jpg"
        });
    });
</script>
```